# Set control text in AutoIt with out window text and title

Tags: autoit

I am quite newbie to autoit. I have 2 questions.

1. How to use ControlFocus ( "", "", "[X:643;Y:339]" ) when widow has no text and no title.Please look at following information of window and control viewed by window informer.

> > > > Window <<<<
> > > >         Title:
> > > >         Class: WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.33c0d9d
> > > >         Position: 0, 0
> > > >         Size: 1024, 768
> > > >         Style: 0x16010000
> > > >         ExStyle: 0x00010000
> > > >         Handle: 0x005201E0
> > > >
> > > > Control <<<<
> > > >         Class: WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.33c0d9d
> > > >         Instance: 2
> > > >         ClassnameNN: WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.33c0d9d2
> > > >         Name: txtConsumerNo
> > > >         Advanced (Class): [NAME:txtConsumerNo]
> > > >         ID: 15270262
> > > >         Text:
> > > >         Position: 638, 237
> > > >         Size: 263, 30
> > > >         ControlClick Coords: 38, 27
> > > >         Style: 0x560100C0
> > > >         ExStyle: 0x00000200
> > > >         Handle: 0x00E90176

How is it possible to interact with this control?

2. I want to call text change event of a this control. How is it possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are dealing with a window without text and a title, it may be easier to first get the handle to the window with WinGetHandle. You can get the handle from the active window like so:

```
$hWnd = WinGetHandle("[ACTIVE]")
```

For interacting with the control you have a lot of options. Your best option is probably to use the Name of the control, which is: txtConsumerNo. If you then use ControlFocus like so it will work. Note that $hWnd comes from the above WinGetHandle statement.

```
ControlFocus($hWnd, "", "[NAME:txtConsumerNo]")
```

I recommend against using the X and Y position of the control. It can have a hard time finding the correct control. When other methods are available, such as the name or the class, those are very much preferred.

You can change the text of another control in AutoIt with the ControlSetText method. It will call the 'text change event' for you automatically. See the help file for the documentation about ControlSetText. It works in a similar way to ControlFocus.

Comment: Thanks to Manadar.I do this as 
first i find handle of window by WinGetHandle("[ACTIVE]")
then i use the ControlSetText(window Handle, "", "Control Name", "text to send" ).It work like a charm.but i am still working on text change event .please let me know if you know how to place your function behind event as you do in c# or jave.

Comment: To truly get a text change event **of another window** is not possible. That's a Windows restriction, not an AutoIt restriction. However, something that comes very close: Make a while loop, ControlGetText, compare captured text with previously captured text. If the text has changed then you call your own text changed method. This can be very fast, and it will probably solve your problem. If you cannot fit it into an existing while loop, then you can try AdlibRegister to call a method that checks the text changed.

Comment: Is there a possibility by using DLL call.If you have any idea please share.

Comment: There is the possibility of doing a shell hook on the window. It's definitely taking a big **detour**, but you are free to go ahead with it: http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/56536-easy-shell-hooking-example/